# Can you come up with any more examples?

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to look at the set of functions $\{f : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}\}$ such that proving $f(s) = 0 \implies s+s^* = 1 $ ($\Re(s) = 1/2$) is easy.  Here are two examples:

$$
f(s) = s - 1/2 \\
f(s) = 1/e^{a (s - 1/2)} - 1 \\
f(s) = e^{a (s - 1/2)} - 1 
$$

Can you come up with others?

Comment: Can you come up with a more informative title? As for examples, take a product of the form $\prod (z-1/2-b_k i)$ where $b_k$ can be any real numbers.